# Dynamic Date and Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datetime

I am trying to build an appointment form. For which I have used [xdsoft Jquery](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) Date and time picker. After selecting a date it checks for the appointments time and returns available time for schedule by ajax. when I alert the data I get the result but I dont get that data in my picker. Any help will be helpful. Tnx

Here's what I tried

**DEMO WIthout AJAX**

http://jsfiddle.net/4PPJ2/1/

**HTML**

```
    <form id="schedule_time_form" method="post" action="#">
      <label>Select Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="datepicker_time" name="datepicker_time" class="input-medium">
      <label>Select Time From</label>
      <input type="text" id="timepicker1_time" disabled name="timpepicker1_time" class="input-small">
   </form>
```

jQuery

```
var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
    if( currentDateTime ){
        var day = "day="+currentDateTime.getDay();
        $.ajax({
            url : "helper/getdate.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : day,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {                   
                $('#timepicker1_time').datetimepicker({
                    datepicker:false,
                    format:'H:i',
                    allowTimes:[data]
                });

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {

            }
        });
    }
};                  

$('#datepicker_time').datetimepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    timepicker:false,
    format:'Y-m-d',
    onChangeDateTime:logic,
    inline: true,

});
```

Comment: And you tagged this as php because ...

Comment: I get the ajax data via php... I din't pasted that code here because its working fine. when I alert data after I get success in ajax it shows result but it does not work

Comment: Then you may think of removing PHP tag.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center, and then edit your question accordingly.  You should also consider providing a link to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: hey guys I added the demo what I am trying is to get dynamic time in  "allowTimes" of dateptimepicker.